# Sharepoint update field based on lookup

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint online list "myList" with fields PersonName, OriginCountry and OriginCity and another list of countries and cities called "WorldList" with columns Country and City.
In myList the user will select their city using a lookup to Worldlist.  I want the country field to update based on what is entered into the city field.
What's the best way to do this?
I would like to do this without a webPart, Powerapp or Flow, but will use them if necessary.  I would prefer to use a Flow rather than a Powerapp or webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the OriginCity lookup column in myList from WorldList, please add an additional column country as shown below:

[image]

If you don’t want to show the additional column in list view, you can hide the column.

Then create a flow to update the OriginCountry value using the additional column "OriginCity:Country":

[image]

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

**-------------------------Update----------------------------------**

Note, exclude OriginCountry ID, other columns will use the property under "when you created or modified the item" option.

[image]

Comment: How do you make sure it only updates the new or updated record rather than the whole list?

Comment: Please check the updated reply.